# Explain how the output came like this

Tags: python-3.x

```
char="#"
length=4
string="JOHN"
print('{0}{1}{0}'.format(char*length, string))
```

OUTPUT:
    ####JOHN####

How did the output come this? How is char and length multiplied?

Comment: Hi Keagan, I guess you are new to Python? `char*length` means that a new string is created consisting of `char` concatenated 4 times (since `length` equals 4). So `"#"*4` equals `"####"`.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `"{0}{1}{0}"` means "use the first argument, then the second, then the first again", so it will output `char*length`, `string`, then `char*length` again.

The expression `<string> * <integer>` means the `<string>` repeated `<integer>` times. So `"#" * 4` is `"####"`. Another example of this would be `"pax" * 2 == "paxpax"`.

So you're basically getting `####`, then `JOHN`, then `####`, as you can see.

That's basically it, there's no real magic going on here. Unless you subscribe to the fact that *all* of Python is magic, which some of us do :-)